# Unable to directly edit HTML, would like to alphabetize table rows by first column

Tags: jquery

I would like to list the names that is pulled from a database in alphabetical order. However the first two rows are heading info and do not need to be sorted. This is built using software, I cannot directly edit the HTML of the page.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#d3d3d3"> 
        <td colspan="4" class="white"><b>Click on the Runner's name that you would like to make a donation to: </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#c4c4c4"> 
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>City/State</b></td>
        <td><b>Team</b></td>
        <td><b>Donation Total</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        <td><a onmouseout="status=&quot;&quot;;return true;" onmouseover="status=&quot;donate now&quot;;return true;" href="#">Jacob Lewis&nbsp;</a></td>
        <td>Richmond VA &nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">$175.00&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td><a onmouseout="status=&quot;&quot;;return true;" onmouseover="status=&quot;donate now&quot;;return true;" href="#">Sarah Haynes&nbsp;</a></td>
        <td>Richmond VA &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">$175.00&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee"><td><a onmouseout="status=&quot;&quot;;return true;" onmouseover="status=&quot;donate now&quot;;return true;" href="#">London Alexander</a></td>
        <td>Midlothian VA &nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">$25.00&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td><a onmouseout="status=&quot;&quot;;return true;" onmouseover="status=&quot;donate now&quot;;return true;" href="#">Margaret Smith</a></td><td>richmond VA &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">$30.00&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a link with the HTML in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/rh8cdbwb/1/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you can't edit the page....do you want to screen scrap the page and create a new page with the data sorted?  Or maybe you just need the TableTools2 add-on for FireFox.

Comment: You selected jQuery - but if you can't edit the html directly how are you going to insert the script?

Comment: $( "tr:gt(1)" ) is the selector for rows after the 2nd row. Is that the part you were stuck on?

Comment: I can edit the header and footer of the entire site, I use jquery apply a script to a particular page. The data changes as more participants register they are added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you can do something like this

```
$('table tbody tr:gt(2)') // get all tr's after the second one
.sort(function(a,b){ // sort the elements in the set
    return 
    // if a > b - return 1
    $(a).find('td:first').text() > $(b).find('td:first').text() ? 1 :
    // if a < b - return -1 / else return 0
    $(a).find('td:first').text() < $(b).find('td:first').text() ? -1 : 0 ;
}).appendTo('table tbody'); // append back to tbody
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhah70hp/)

Comment: Thanks, but the fiddle doesn't seem to sort alphabetically, instead it is sorting by the amount raised in the last column. Is there a way to sort alphabetically?